# Can't send POST in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following problem.
I have the method that sends json via POST:

```
public string request (string handler, string data) 
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(baseUri + "/?h=" + handler);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "text/json";

    string json = "json=" + data;
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(json);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    Stream str = request.GetRequestStream();
    str.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    str.Close();

    WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
    lastResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return lastResponse;
}
```

When using the method on the server does not come data in POST. As if this code is not executed.

```
Stream str = request.GetRequestStream();
str.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
str.Close();
```

On the server i'm using following php script for debug:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Also tried to write to the stream as follows:

```
StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
strw.Write(json);
strw.Close();
```

The result - a zero response. In response comes an empty array.

Comment: Have you tried watching the traffic in Fiddler?

Comment: No, i did not know about this. I'll try it now.

Comment: Yes, in the fiddler i can see my post data. In the TextView inspector. It means that i'm using wrong php script?

Comment: Change the content-type to `request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` and the `json`-initialization to `string json = "json=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that PHP does not "recognize" the `text/json`-content type. And thus does not parse the POST-request-data. You have to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type and secondly you have to encode the POST-data properly:

```
// ...
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

string json = "json=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data);
// ...
```

If you intend to supply the JSON-data directly you can leave the content-type to `text/json` and pass the data directly as `json` (without the "json=" part):

```
string json = data;
```

But in that case you have to change your script on the PHP-side to directly read the post data:

```
// on your PHP side:
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($post_body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using WebClient.UploadValues.  Using the NameValueCollection with "json" as the name and JSON data string as the value?

This seems like the easiest way to go.  Don't forget you can always add headers and credentials to the WebClient.